# PrimeFaces PickList : source and target lists not updated

Tags: primefaces, target, empty-list, picklist

I am setting up a primefaces picklist and the source and target lists stay empty.

page.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <p:pickList id="picklist" value="#{bean.users}" var="user" 
        itemValue="#{user}" itemLabel="#{user.login}" converter="userConverter">  

    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Source</f:facet>  
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Target</f:facet>  

    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{bean.onTransfer}" />    

    <p:column style="width:75%;">  
        <h:outputText value="#{user.login}" />  
    </p:column>  

    </p:pickList>

    <h:commandButton id="submit" type="submit" actionListener="#{bean.submit}" value="Submit" />
    <h:commandButton id="display" actionListener="#{bean.displayTargetList}" value="Display Target List" />
</form>
```

bean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<User> source;
    private List<User> target;
    private DualListModel<User> users;

    public void setTarget(List<User> list) {
        this.target = list;
    }

    public void setSource(List<User> list) {
        this.source = list;
    }

    public void setUsers(DualListModel<User> list) {
        this.users = list;
    }

    public DualListModel<User> getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public List<User> getSource() {
        return this.source;
    }

    public List<User> getTarget() {
        return this.target;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.source = myController.getUsers(); // return all my users in database
        this.target = new ArrayList<User>();
        this.users = new DualListModel<User>(this.source, this.target);
    }

    public void submit() {

    }

    public void displayTargetList() {
        System.out.println("Entering function");
        Iterator<User> iterator = this.target.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            User u = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(u.getLogin());
        }
    }

}
```

And there is the converter

userConverter.java

```
@FacesConverter("userConverter")
public class UserConverter implements Converter{

    private List<User> users;

    public UserConverter(){
        this.users = MyController.getAllUsers();
    }

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return this.getUserById(value);
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return ((User) value).getId();
    }

    public User getUserById(String id) {
        // return the user searching from this.users
    }
}
```

The code I have is a little more complex but I hope the mistake is here. For me it seems to be implemented like the primefaces showcase. I could add that the method getAsObject in the converter return an object (I tried to print before returning the value and the objects wasn't null)

If you can help.
Thanks

Comment: The problem was the source and target lists are not updated directly. I need to use `users.getTarget()` and `users.getSource()` to see the modifications.